# Transformation doesn't transorm line segments in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to annotate a plot using some line segments. The x-axis is best displayed by a log transformation. I am using `ggplot2` which handles transformations, which also means I shouldn't have to transform to location of my line segments. But when I apply a transformation, the line segments disappear (well - they don't "fit" into the plot window any more, due to the transformation). Any suggestions on how to get them to "follow" the transformation?

Minimal example:

```
library(ggplot2)
## Base plot:
B <- ggplot(data = data.frame(X = 10^(1:10), Y = 1:10),
            aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point()
## Generate segments: 
S1 <- geom_segment(x = 1000, xend = 1000,
                   y = 3, yend = 5)
S2 <- geom_segment(x = 20, xend = 2.5e9,
                   y = 8, yend = 7)
## Generate transformation:
T <- scale_x_continuous(trans = "log")
```

Compare the following:

```
B               # Basic plot
B + T           # Basic plot, transformed
B + S1 + S2     # Basic, untransformed, with segments
B + S1 + S2 + T # Should be transformed with segments: segments missing
```

I know I could just transform the locations of the segments, but I'd really rather find a more `ggplot2`-style solution!

Hack solution:

```
S3 <- geom_segment(x = log(1000), xend = log(1000),
                   y = 3, yend = 5)
S4 <- geom_segment(x = log(20), xend = log(2.5e9),
                   y = 8, yend = 7)
B + S1 + S2
B + S3 + S4 + T #Fine, but not elegant.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the plot I've shown is what you expect. But if it is, the explanation below is valid.

In `ggplot2` transformations are performed on `aesthetics`. And the data is transformed first before plotting (or doing anything of the sort of fitting, ex: geom_smooth etc.. is done on transformed data).

So, if you want the log transformation to be reflected on your segment, you'll have to wrap around with `aes` as:

```
S1 <- geom_segment(aes(x=1000, xend=1000, y=3, yend=5))
S2 <- geom_segment(aes(x=20, xend=2.5e9, y=8, yend=7))
```

And by the way, your transformation should be **log10, NOT log**:

```
T <- scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

Now, if you plot `B + S1 + S2 + T`:

[image: ggplot2_aes]

One step further: Compare your `B+S1+S2+T` and the one with `S1` and `S2` modified with mine using:

```
ggplot_build(B+S1+S2)$data # and 
ggplot_build(B+S1+S2+T)$data
```

to see that the aesthetics get transformed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! True about the `log10` - was just trying to minimise my minimal example, but I went too far.