# Segment annotation on log10 scale works differently for the end and the beginning of the segment?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, logarithm

I found a rather confusing feature in ggplot while trying to annotate segments on log10 scale. Following code produces the plot below:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = x <- 1:1000, y = log(x)) 
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_line(size = 2) + scale_x_log10() +
annotate("segment", x = 0, xend = log10(100), y = log(100), yend = log(100), linetype = 2) +
annotate("segment", x = log10(100), xend = log10(100), y = 0, yend = log(100), linetype = 2)
```

[image]

Whereas this is what I am after:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_line(size = 2) + scale_x_log10() +
annotate("segment", x = 0, xend = log10(100), y = log(100), yend = log(100), linetype = 2) +
annotate("segment", x = 100, xend = log10(100), y = 0, yend = log(100), linetype = 2)
```

[image]

In other words, I have to log10 transform the endpoint of the segment on x-axis, but not the beginning. Does this behaviour have a logical explanation? I understand that [`aes()` does the transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984110/transformation-doesnt-transorm-line-segments-in-ggplot2)...but in this case, transformations on x-axis should be uniform (well, log10), right?

I am working on:

```
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
ggplot2_0.9.3.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that this is a bug of `scales()` (not only for the `scale_x_log10()`) when it is used with `annotate()` and `xend` value is provided (it is [already filled](http://osdir.com/ml/ggplot2/2012-10/msg00281.html) as issue by W.Chang). In this case transformation of `xend` is done only in one direction - log10 of value is not taked but power is calculated.

`scale_x_log10()` works without problems if, for example, `"rect"` is used in `annotate()` and `xmin`, `xmax` values are provided.

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x,y))+geom_line()+
  scale_x_log10()+
  annotate("rect",xmin=100,xmax=1000,ymin=log(10),ymax=log(200))
```

[image]

Workaround for this problem would be to use `geom_segment()` with `data=NULL` and all other values put inside the `aes()`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) + scale_x_log10() +
  geom_segment(data=NULL,aes(x = 100, xend = 100, y = 0, yend = log(100)), 
                                                             linetype = 2)
```

[image]